# Ways to swap local files between mobiles

Tags: android, ios, file-transfer

I have the next problem:

To my graduation work my teacher told me to implement a system that allows me to transfer any type of file from a phone (Android, IOS...) to another phone (Android, IOS...) using a server that keeps the files until the target phone downloads it.

Could anyone give me some advice about the best way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks in advance? You should at least invite us for your graduation party!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Firebase Storage, it has a free plan (so it's nice), and it gives you a nice API in Android and IOS, it allows you to upload and download files easily. 
read more here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/